# Two inputs same form column taking all the cell width Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get hands over Bootstrap 3 and I'm kindof struggling with the new classes for the grid. Previous versions of Bootstrap let you set the width of a input by adding the span-* class so if you wanted to put two inputs on the same form column, adding span-2 and span-10 did the job. I'm trying to do this with bootstrap 3 but I don't get the same result as you can see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FXEW3/), I want to set the select and the input on the same col. I want the labels at top of the inputs so adding the `inline class` to the form don't work.

What I'm missing here?

Cheers and thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### http://jsbin.com/esewOyo/1/

Most people can't believe how many classes are involved but form-control is always 100% so each one must go inside a col-*-* class and if you want to put elements on the same row, in this situation, then you'd use a nested row with columns as follows:

```
<div class="container">
 <form role="form">
  <div class="row my-row">
   <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label>C-Band</label>
       <select class="form-control">
        <option value="C15+">C15+</option>
        <option value="C12-14">C12-14</option>
        <option>
       </select>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label>&nbsp;</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label>C-Band</label>
     <select class="form-control">
      <option value="C15+">C15+</option>
      <option value="C12-14">C12-14</option>
      <option>
     </select>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label>C-Band</label>
     <select class="form-control">
      <option value="C15+">C15+</option>
      <option value="C12-14">C12-14</option>
      <option>
     </select>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label>C-Band</label>
     <select class="form-control">
      <option value="C15+">C15+</option>
      <option value="C12-14">C12-14</option>
      <option>
     </select>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label>C-Band</label>
     <select class="form-control">
      <option value="C15+">C15+</option>
      <option value="C12-14">C12-14</option>
      <option>
     </select>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

Because the gutter is too wide for my taste:

```
.row.my-row, .row.my-row .row {
  margin-left:-1%;
  margin-right:-1%
}

.row.my-row [class*="col-"] {
 padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%; 
}

.row.my-row .row [class*="col-"] {
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
}
```