# Bootstrap multiple "fixed-width inputs" in 1 Column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to achieve that the following is on 1 line

http://jsfiddle.net/strgga/6yanLf8q/30/

```css
.rightstraight {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 0;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0;
}
.leftstraight {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0;
}
.input-group-addon.primary {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(50, 118, 177);
  border-color: rgb(40, 94, 142);
}
.input-group-addon.success {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(92, 184, 92);
  border-color: rgb(76, 174, 76);
}
.input-group-addon.info {
  //  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  //  background-color: rgb(57, 179, 215);
  //  border-color: rgb(38, 154, 188);
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.input-group-addon.warning {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(240, 173, 78);
  border-color: rgb(238, 162, 54);
}
.input-group-addon.danger {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(217, 83, 79);
  border-color: rgb(212, 63, 58);
}
.has-feedback .form-control-feedback {
  right: 0px !important;
  top: 0;
  padding-right: 4px !important;
}
.form-control-feedback {
  width: 22px !important;
  text-align: left !important;
}
.has-feedback .form-control {
  padding-right: 22px !important;
}
.righta {
  text-align: right;
}
.middla {
  text-align: center;
}
.slim {
  width: 61px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <h2>Gratisofferte</h2>
  <form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
    <div id="form1">
      <div class="form-group ">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-5">
          <label>Aktuelle Adresse</label>
          <div class=" has-feedback has-success">
            <input class="rightstraight form-control" placeholder="z.B. Paradiesstrasse 10" type="text" id="n_adr">
            <span id="fname1" class="glyphicon form-control-feedback glyphicon-ok"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4" style="margin-left:-30px;">
          <label>PLZ</label>
          <input class="leftstraight form-control" placeholder="PLZ" type="text" id="n_plz">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-3">
          <label>Zimmer</label>
          <select class="slim form-control">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
          </select>


          <label>Etage</label>
          <select class="slim form-control">
            <option>E</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
          </select>

          <label>Lift</label>
          <select class="slim form-control">
            <option>ja</option>
            <option>nein</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <button id="next" type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">weiter</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </form>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Why bootstrap doesn't put the selects on one line? They are in a column bounded?

Comment: why do you comment css that way?

Comment: Can you a rough sketch like wireframe, what u exactly want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Check this you need like this way..**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/6yanLf8q/32/)**

```
    <div class="container"> 
  <h2>Gratisofferte</h2>
   <form role="form">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">

            <label>Aktuelle Adresse</label>

            <input class="form-control " placeholder="z.B. Paradiesstrasse 10" type="text" id="n_adr">
                <span id="fname1" class="glyphicon form-control-feedback glyphicon-ok"></span>
</div>  <div class="form-group col-md-2">

            <label>PLZ</label>
            <input class="leftstraight form-control" placeholder="PLZ" type="text" id="n_plz">
        </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label>Zimmer</label>
            <select class="slim form-control">  <option>1</option>  <option>2</option>  <option>3</option>  <option>4</option></select>
        </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label>Etage</label>
      <select class="slim form-control">  <option>E</option><option>1</option>  <option>2</option>  <option>3</option>  <option>4</option></select></div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label>Lift</label>
            <select class="slim form-control">  <option>ja</option>  <option>nein</option></select>

        </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-1">

         <button id="next" type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">weiter</button>
      </div>

</form>
<hr>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but i really need it with upper labels like in my demo. not the label on the left

Answer (score 0):

The answer is given from christina in this post

[Two inputs same form column taking all the cell width Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21126533/two-inputs-same-form-column-taking-all-the-cell-width-bootstrap-3)

The solution lies in the nesting of rows, therefor making it thiner=exacter than within the 12-part grid. So you put a first grid in 4-4-4 and than you can create a grid in each of this grids again. this way you can achieve more than a 12-tel of a grid. For example you can split the last column in 5-5-1 which results in a total break-down of 13 % - 13 % and 2.7 % (= a 12-tel of 0.33).

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Gratisofferte</h2>
  <form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
 <div id="form1">
    <div class="form-group ">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-5">
   <label>Aktuelle Adresse</label>
            <div class=" has-feedback has-success">
   <input class="rightstraight form-control" placeholder="z.B. Paradiesstrasse 10" type="text" id="n_adr">
                <span id="fname1" class="glyphicon form-control-feedback glyphicon-ok"></span></div>
</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4" style="margin-left:-30px;">
   <label>PLZ</label>
            <input class="leftstraight form-control" placeholder="PLZ" type="text" id="n_plz">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-3">
            <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4"  style="">
   <label>Zimmer</label>
   <select class="slim form-control">  <option>1</option>  <option>2</option>  <option>3</option>  <option>4</option></select>
  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4" style="margin-left:-30px;">
   <label>Etage</label>
   <select class="slim form-control">  <option>E</option><option>1</option>  <option>2</option>  <option>3</option>  <option>4</option></select>
                </div>
                                  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4" style="margin-left:-30px;">
   <label>Lift</label>
   <select class="slim form-control">  <option>ja</option>  <option>nein</option></select>
            </div>        
  </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
         <button id="next" type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">weiter</button>
      </div>
    </div>
                   
          </div>
</form>
<hr>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/strgga/6yanLf8q/33/

As for the question i don't know any way to put above-labels in place without putting the input-label combo in a seperate col. maybe with custom css only.